# URL request length limit when using REST APIs

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

Are there any URL length limitation when making a GET request using REST API to SharePoint? I've been investigating for a while now, all I can see are inconsistent answers.

Microsoft documentation only shows url length limitation when using SharePoint browser. I am currently making an external application that uses REST API calls, but there seems to be a problem with the length of the URL.

Comment: Get request in what? in list items or others? for list items, there is alternate solution using CAML and POST request

Comment: like request for retrieving list of subsites/document libraries/folders/files

Comment: See my answer for list and libraries. It is not possible for others AFAIK.

Comment: Can you post an example for subsite which is exceeding the default limit?

Comment: Structure is like this: `/<very long subsite path>/_api/web/GetSubwebsFilteredForCurrentUser(nwebtemplatefilter=-1)?$select=Title,ServerRelativeUrl&$skip=0&$top=50`.

Comment: Not a realistic folder name. Not a good practice either. Rename your folder otherwise you will be stuck here because no solution for SharePoint online

Comment: I am trying to investigate the url length limitation of a REST API request that is why i am using long folder url names

Answer (score 1):

Default **GET** request **URL** length is 260. It can be modified in on-premise but in online it is not possible.Follow [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/8346a849-2e0c-4300-b68d-d7ab850d854c/the-length-of-the-url-for-this-request-exceeds-the-configured-maxurllength-value?forum=appsforsharepoint) link to modify this default value in On-Premise.

If your GET request **URL** length exceeds for getting items from a list, then you can solve it using **CAML** query and **POST** request. Example:

## End-point

```
/_api/Web/Lists/getbytitle('List Name')/GetItems
```

## Request Body

```
{
  __metadata: {
    type: "SP.CamlQuery" 
  },
  ViewXml: 'CAML Query goes here'
}
```

Most of the cases, I found URL length exceeds for `$filter` operator. So `$filter` can be solved using CAML query.

- Build your **CAML** query using [U2U Caml Query Builder](https://www.u2u.be/Software)
- Test/Explore **REST API** using [SP REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sp-rest-client/ojnaikgchcnginnmkmkonmdglhjikokd)

Comment: I have tried counting the actual URL length, it is okay until 260 (not including the domain [https://], endpoint [something.sharepoint.com] and OData operators [...?$skip=0,..]

Comment: you are right. answer updated

Comment: @AtishDipongkor-MVP can you explain how query should be constructed in the viewXml for fields which need to be extended?